# How to use facebook-opengraph plugin for login in yii

Tags: php, facebook, yii

hi i am trying to use facebook graph api for login through facebook. i am using code below to show login

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.yii-facebook-opengraph.plugins.LoginButton', array(
'show_faces'=>true,
'registration_url'=>'http://mysite/index.php/users/facebookregister',
'oauth'=>true,  // JS SDK -enable OAuth 2.0
)); ?>
```

and in the redirected page i am doing

```
<?php $userinfo = Yii::app()->facebook->getInfo() // gets the Graph info of the current user ?>

but it gives me error
Property "LoginButton.oauth" is not defined. 

i am follwing this url to http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/facebook-opengraph/
```

Comment: make sure that you have followed the instructions on the extensions page and configured correctly. make sure that oauth is set to true in the components array in your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oauth property is not assigned within the widget but within the components array in your config file (most probably main.php).

```
'components'=>array(
  'facebook'=>array(
    'class' => 'ext.yii-facebook-opengraph.SFacebook',
    'appId'=>'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', // needed for JS SDK, Social Plugins and PHP SDK
    'secret'=>'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET', // needed for the PHP SDK 
    //'locale'=>'en_US', // override locale setting (defaults to en_US)
    //'jsSdk'=>true, // don't include JS SDK
    //'async'=>true, // load JS SDK asynchronously
    //'jsCallback'=>false, // declare if you are going to be inserting any JS callbacks to the async JS SDK loader
    //'status'=>true, // JS SDK - check login status
    //'cookie'=>true, // JS SDK - enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    //'oauth'=>true,  // JS SDK -enable OAuth 2.0
    //'xfbml'=>true,  // JS SDK - parse XFBML / html5 Social Plugins
    //'html5'=>true,  // use html5 Social Plugins instead of XFBML
    //'ogTags'=>array(  // set default OG tags
        //'title'=>'MY_WEBSITE_NAME',
        //'description'=>'MY_WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION',
        //'image'=>'URL_TO_WEBSITE_LOGO',
    //),
  ),
),
```